# making query with multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, union

```
SELECT keyword 
FROM
(
    SELECT tutor_Name AS keyword FROM t
    UNION
    SELECT subject_name AS keyword FROM s
    UNION
    SELECT institute_name AS keyword FROM i
) s
WHERE keyword LIKE '%$queryString%' 
LIMIT 10
```

this query display a list with subjects, tutor names, cities according the keyword. Now I need to modify this query with more values. For an example there is a tutor name in the list I want to display his/her current city, his/her profile image etc. So I need to get those values from my city table, address table, tutorImages table.. So anybody can help me to make this query?

Comment: What have you tried? We're not here to make your work ;). But I guess you want the `JOIN` command.

Comment: Specify what are the columns do you want to display and use JOINs to do the same

Comment: read this maybe it will help http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: I tried it with INNER JOIN. but my problem is I cant get to work with this query. Reason is above query select subjects,tutors,institutes and cities all together. so there I need to add tutor's city name and his/her profile image only for the tutors in the list.. That is the problem I face...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this it will work:

```
$q = "SELECT keyword, col, city_name, image_name, tutor_code 
            FROM (
                SELECT tutor_name AS keyword, 'Tutors' AS col, IFNULL(c1.city_name, '') city_name, IFNULL(ti.image_name, '') image_name, tutor_code FROM tutors AS t
                LEFT JOIN address a ON t.address_id = a.address_id
                LEFT JOIN city c1 ON a.city_id = c1.city_id 
                LEFT JOIN tutor_images ti ON t.tutor_id = ti.tutor_id and ti.image_type = 'profile'
                UNION
                SELECT subjects AS keyword, 'Subject' AS col, '' city_name, '' image_name, '' tutor_code FROM subject
                UNION
                SELECT city_name AS keyword, 'City' AS col, '' city_name, '' image_name, '' tutor_code FROM city
                UNION
                SELECT institute_name AS keyword, 'Institute' AS col, '' city_name, '' image_name, '' tutor_code FROM institutes
            ) s
          WHERE keyword LIKE '%$queryString%' 
          LIMIT 10";
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your first query is, that you fetch all results of each table unfiltered, union them, distinct them, then filter the result. This is quite ineffective in terms of query time and resources.

What you need here are JOINs.
To understand how joins work, read this

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

and this

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html

To give you an idea of how your query should look like: the old one refactored

```
SELECT
```

give me a moment, switching from mobile to pc.. Read the article while ;)

Sorry, took a bit longer. I see you have found a solution meanwhile so I will not bother digging into this longer

Comment: can I have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT keyword, city_name, image_name
FROM (
SELECT tname AS keyword, IFNULL(c1.city_name, '') city_name, IFNULL(ti.image_name, '') image_name FROM t 
LEFT JOIN address a ON t.address_id = a.address_id
LEFT JOIN city c1 ON a.city_id = c1.city_id 
LEFT JOIN tutorImages ti ON t.tutor_id = t1.tutor_id 
UNION
SELECT sname AS keyword, '' city_name, '' image_name FROM sub
UNION
SELECT cname AS keyword, '' city_name, '' image_name FROM c
UNION
SELECT iname AS keyword, '' city_name, '' image_name FROM i ) s
WHERE keyword LIKE '%$queryString%' 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: I modified your query and where clause to the sub query like this WHERE ti.image_type = 'profile'. It is working. But If tutors dont have profile image those tutors not display in the list.. can you tell me why is it? Thanks

Comment: It's not possible because we had used LEFT JOIN so query will return all tutors whether he/she has image or not. and check my updated answer

Comment: when I useing IFNULL there is an error in my query.. it is 'Incorrect parameter count in the call to the native function "IFNULL"'. What this message mean? NOTE: I am using LEFT JOIN for tutorImage table

Comment: Check the answer. I forgot to put second parameter of IFNULL function.

Comment: I changed the query. But problem is same. if a profile image dont have to a tutor who is not display in the list.

Comment: Use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN. It will solve the problem

Comment: I used LEFT JOIN.. But nothing happen. what is the wrong with this?

Comment: I added my complete query.. check question

Comment: did you? actually what has happen there?

Comment: can anybody tell me what has happen in my query?

Answer (score 0):

Try a join.

```
SELECT table1.field, table2.field, table3.field 
FROM table1 
JOIN table2 ON table1columnToMatch = table2columnToMatch
JOIN table3 ON table2columnToMatch = table3columnToMatch
WHERE tableWithKeyword.keyword = $keyword
```